# newsyslog for paths with empty spaces

Tags: osx, logs

How can I configure newsyslog to trim logs with paths containing empty spaces?

I define my paths at /etc/newsyslog.d/frank.conf like this:

```
"/Users/frank/Library/Application Support/Google/Drive/*.log"    644  0     5120 *    GN
```

I also tried this:

```
/Users/frank/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Drive/*.log    644  0     5120 *    GN
```

However I always get the error:

```
newsyslog: error in config file; unknown user:
```

So far I can solve the problem by using a static link with no empty spaces, but I really would like a solution without that hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asterisks... E.g.:

```
/Users/frank/Library/Application*Support/Google/Drive/*.log
```

I use newsyslog to clean my Navicat Lite logs in the library/application support folder like so:

```
# logfilename                                                       [owner:group]   mode    count   size    when    flags   [/pid_file]     [sig_num]
/Users/eric/Library/Application*Support/Navicat*Lite/*.log                          644     5       1000    *       G
```

The G flag specifies that shell globbing is to be performed on the filename.

PS The error unknown user refers to the missing user:group field after the filename.